# Does a Nested @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) Create a New Hibernate Session?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

When starting a new transaction, using `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`) in a current transaction, that was started using `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)`, is a new Session created for the new Transaction?

Is there a way to use only one session for all transactions if the above is true?

Here is a visual example:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED
public void startParentTransaction() {

    ChildObject childObject = newChildTransaction();
    childObject.lazyLoadedAttribute();

    ChildObject childObject = newChildTransaction();
    childObject.lazyLoadedAttribute();
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW
public ChildObject newChildTransaction() {

    ChildObject childObject = callRepositoryOrDao();
    childObject.changeState();
    return childObject;
}
```

Will the call to the `childOjbect.lazyLoadedAttribute()` work?  Or will a `LazyInitializationException` be thrown?

Can we have all the transactions happen in one `Session`?

Answer (score 0):

You're bound to Spring `@Transactional` annotation.

Normally, `Propagation.REQUIRE_NEW` will start a new transaction even there's existint transaction.

But if you call the `newChildTransaction` locally (just is within the same method), then the spring AOP does not have a chance to interact with the `@Transaction` annotation.

Hence in this case, the `newChildTransaction()` use the existing transaction

Comment: Thanks for the information, but is there a new session per transaction?

Comment: Nope. All transaction of a single request are in a same session. Transaction will be created as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so what could be causing our LazyInitializationException to occur when we are accessing a lazy loaded attribute outside of the initiating (child) transaction?

Comment: When you access a lazied collection, hibernate must query again to get the data. If the access is outside of an transaction, the query cannot be executed

Comment: It's not need to be necessarily accessed in the initiating transaction, but can be in any transaction